# Disable hardware beep for warning in /var/log/syslog

Tags: linux, debian, openvpn

I have a fresh Debian installation and configured OpenVPN.
OpenVPN produces some warnings about deprecations in my client.conf.

Every time a new warning pops up in `/var/log/syslog`, my notebook (Lenovo Thinkpad T490s) makes a hardware (mainboard) beep sound.

Here is an example warning from `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Feb  7 14:25:28 MY-PC systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN connection to client.
Feb  7 14:25:28 MY-PC ovpn-client[4130]: OpenVPN 2.5.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 14 2021
Feb  7 14:25:28 MY-PC ovpn-client[4130]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021, LZO 2.10
Feb  7 14:25:28 MY-PC ovpn-client[4130]: WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
```

I fixed the deprecation warnings but how can i turn those beep sounds off so that not every warning that may come up in the future results in a hardware beep?

It is not the Terminal beep. The mainboard beeps when there is a warning in `/var/log/syslog`.